# Active Record undefined method read_attribute_for_serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails scope that gets the first record of a table and assings it to a @variable. It returns either a single object or an empty Active Record Relation. My problem is that i'm using a custom serializer to render the json but if the scope returns an empty Active Record Relation I get the "Active Record undefined method read_attribute_for_serialization" unless i use each_serializer, but if the the scope returns an object i have to render it using serializer: 
Is there any way of solving this without doing this :

```
if @variable.blank?
  render json: @variable, each_serializer: CustomSerializer
else
  render json: @variable, serializer: CustomSerializer
end
```

**Update**

I have to get the latest record from the Products table.
So i have defined a scope like this:

```
scope :last_by_period, -> { order('period desc').first }
```

So this scope returns an empty Active Record Relation if there are no Products records in my db.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. What sort of object is `@variable` going to be?

Comment: @tadman i have updated my post

Answer (score 3):

> either a single object or an empty Active Record Relation

I think this is the issue. I think you should either

- always return a collection. a collection of a single object or empty collection
- either return a single object or nil

With the first option, you could always use `each_serializer`. With the second option, you could always use `serializer`.

Comment: The issue is that if I use the default serializer I don't have this problem. Isn't there anything i can do?